# concat this with method parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to concat this with method parameter for access data
 this is my data:

```
  data: function() {
    return {
        items: ['x', 'y', 'z','c','k'],
        selectedItems: [],
    };
```

and this is my method:

```
moveItems: function(destination, source){
       console.log(this.source);
}
```

my problems is when i call my method like this for example:

```
this.moveItems('selectBox1','items')
```

cant compile this.source to this.items and said that it is `undefined`
what is solution for this?

Comment: @birdspider source is parameter of my method and pass value (items) for it !

Comment: `source` is your parameter, `this.source` does not exist in your code snippet.  maybe you mean to do `this[source]` to access `this.items` - but I don't know because the question is rather unclear

Answer (score 0):

In the function `moveItems` you are trying to access `this.source` which is a property of the function's context, here `moveItems` function.

In Vue.JS in the context of a method of a component, you have access to the data as properties of `this`.

Here `destination` and `source` are not declared as data of your component but as parameters of your `moveItems` function.

So if you wanna access to `source` or ``destination` within the context of that function, you should do this :

```
moveItems: function(destination, source){
       console.log(source);
}
```